# openssl/wget only working if i explicitly specify ca-directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, wget

If I try to use openssl or wget without explicitly passing in a ca-directory, the certifcate fails to verify. I would like to get ubuntu back to the original state of verifying normal sites like google.com easily. Is there an env variable i need to set, or a symlink i need to enable to get thhis configured properly?

```
chris@chris:~$ wget --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs https://google.com
--2019-04-13 12:42:12--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.4.206, 2607:f8b0:4009:807::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.4.206|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.google.com/ [following]
--2019-04-13 12:42:12--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 172.217.4.36, 2607:f8b0:4009:80f::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|172.217.4.36|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.5’

index.html.5                                      [ <=>                                                                                             ]  11.07K  --.-KB/s    in 0.004s

2019-04-13 12:42:12 (2.88 MB/s) - ‘index.html.5’ saved [11340]

chris@chris:~$ wget https://google.com
--2019-04-13 12:42:19--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.4.206, 2607:f8b0:4009:807::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.4.206|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify google.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Google Internet Authority G3,O=Google Trust Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Here is the same behavior with openssl if i do not explicitly pass in `-CApath`

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=Google Internet Authority G3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2962 bytes and written 261 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
```

Comment: Use command `c_rehash -v` to find out your openssl's default cert directory (e.g. /usr/local/ssl/certs). Once you know that, you can use copy/symlink the certificates.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond this is the output of that `$ c_rehash -v
chris@chris:~$
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed my problems

`export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: Thanks Chris, just spent 3 hours trying to fix a CERT problem on Ubuntu18.